# Why can't I rotate anymore an object?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I can no longer rotate a object. Can anyone please help me? I don't know what shortcut I pressed because now I can't rotate any object in my scene.

Comment: Look in the Outliner and make sure the "Arrow" icon next to the object hasn't been pressed (Grey). If so just click it (White).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Outliner and make sure the "Arrow" icon next to the object hasn't been pressed (Grey). If so just click it (White).